# Objc - Swift Interoperability: Objc API for Any type?

Tags: swift

I've got an objective c API defined like this:

```
- (instancetype)initWithItems:(NSArray *)items reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier configuration:(void(^)(id item, id cell, NSIndexPath *indexPath))configuration;
```

This translates into Swift like this:

```
public init!(items: [AnyObject]!, reuseIdentifier: String!, configuration: ((AnyObject!, AnyObject!, NSIndexPath!) -> Void)!)
```

Now, I'd like to use this API with an Array of swift structs, but unfortunately I cannot cast the structs to `AnyObject`. Is there any way to write an Objc API with an `id` type that translates to the swift type `Any` so that I can use both a swift class and a struct?

Comment: This will actually be in Swift 3: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0116-id-as-any.md

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't possible to do this, because an `NSArray` can only store `AnyObject`s because they all have the same size (1 pointer). Structs on the other hand have variable size (`Bool` has 1 byte, `Int16` 2 bytes, etc.).

The Swift 3 accepted proposal [Import Objective-C `id` as Swift `Any` type](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0116-id-as-any.md) will probably make this possible:

> Untyped Cocoa collections come in as collections of `Any`.  `NSArray` imports
>     as `[Any]`

You can write a simple class wrapper for now:

```
struct MyStruct {
    let a : Int
    let b : Int
}

final class Box : NSObject {
    let value : MyStruct
    init(value: MyStruct) {
        self.value = value
    }
}

let x = MyStruct(a: 1, b: 2)

let object : AnyObject = Box(value: x)
```

You'll have to test it yourself whether it works with ObjC, especially how accessing the struct properties works, as I don't have any experience with it.

EDIT: You can use [Lightweight Generics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-ID35) in Objective-C, such that `NSArray<Box *>` gets imported to Swift as `[Box]`

Comment: Marking a class @objc is the same as inheriting with NSObject. Either one should do!